Error 400 in google sign-in(React Native)
When I try to use google sign-in methods on youtube in my React Project, I met and error called

Access blocked:TheReactApp's requestis invalid
You can't sign in because TheReactApp sent an invalidrequest. You can try again later, or contact thedeveloper about this issue. Learn more about thiserror
If you are a developer of TheReactApp, see errordetails.
Error 400: invalid request

It happens on my Android emulator, but it works perfectly fine when I try it on the web.
I checked my Client Id, SHA-1 fingerprint and the package name, but all of them are set correctly.
And I also tried to fix this error with ChatGPT by rewriting this file and write me a new file to do the same function, but it shows the same error. For now I don't really know how to handle it.
